# Decoding ANSI escape sequences in Dart

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I'm writing some code for Flutter Desktop targeting linux_x64.
I'm extracting some logs from some applications, these logs presents a syntax like this:

- Inspecting log file using `less logfile`

  ```
  ESC(BESC[mauthentication-msESC(BESC[m
  ```
- Inspecting log file using `less -r logfile` I can see colored text into my terminal.
- Inspecting log file using `cat logfile` I can see colored text into my terminal.
- Inspecting log file using `cat -vte logfile` I get this:

  ```
  ^[(B^[[mauthentication-ms^[(B^[[m$
  ```
- In Flutter using this code

  ```
  Future<String> readAsString = file.readAsString();
  readAsString.then((String value) => _log = utf8.decode(value.runes.toList()));
  ```

  I get this output in a SelectableText widget

  ```
  (B[mauthentication-ms(B[m
  ```

---

I'm really confused about this behaviour so if someone has experience on this suggestions are welcome!

There are 2 options:

- Cleaning all the logs, visualizing normal text
- Trying to decode the text just as `less -r` does, visualizing colored text into Flutter application.

---

**EDIT:**
I solved importing [tint plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/tint): `tint: ^2.0.0`

and changing the Dart code (using the `strip()` method from tint plugin) as follows:

```
Future<String> readAsString = file.readAsString();
readAsString.then((String value) => _log = value.strip());
```

Comment: I couldn't find a more explanatory title for the question, if you can feel free to change it!

Comment: `less` and `cat` aren't decoding the text, your terminal is. What you need to do is make a function that iterates through the string and removes every character between a `\x1b` char and a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those funny characters are called escape sequences, and programs use them to print colours and italics and all of that.

Terminals are designed to decode these escape sequences, but regular programs don't know what to do with them. `less` and `cat` are printing exactly what is in the file, it's the terminal you run them in that decodes them.

You'll have to make your program go through and remove all of the escape sequences with a piece of code like this:

```
m = "h\x1b[34mello\x1b(A.\x1b[H" # Text full of random escape sequences
c = 0 # A count variable
p = True # Are we not in an escape sequence?
o = "" # The output variable
for l in m:
    if l == "\x1b":
        p = False
    elif p:
        o += l
    elif l in "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm": # Most (maybe all) escape sequences end in letters.
        p = True
    c += 1 # Move on to the next letter in the input string
    
print(o) # Text without escape sequences
```

Comment: Wait, I just realised you're not using Python. Anyway, the code should do that sort of thing.

Comment: Don't worry about the language, I'll try to do the same thing in Dart. Anyway thank you, not it is more cear for me. Thans for your time and explanation. I'll update you about the code I'll use.

Comment: see edit if you want to integrate the dart code to solve this! Thank you again :)